# MATLAB and python gives different answer for quaternion

Tags: python, matlab, quaternions

I have a rotation matrix in MATLAB

```matlab
PC=[0.4822    0.5070    0.7145
   -0.4086    0.8516   -0.3285
    0.7750    0.1336   -0.6177]; 

quat=rotm2quat(PC); %gives me 
[0.3937, 0.8641, 0.0319, 0.3119] %which is [w,x,y,z]
```

Same matrix in python

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
rot=[[0.4822 ,   0.5070 ,   0.7145],[-0.4086 ,   0.8516 ,  -0.3285],[ 0.7750 ,   0.1336 ,  -0.6177]]
r=R.from_dcm(rot)
print(r.as_quat()) # gives me following   
[ 0.04920064  0.99356301 -0.09745128 -0.0302504 ] # which is [x,y,z,w]
```

Why the quaternion value `[x,y,z,w]` are not matching between MATLAB and python.

Comment: I notice that your Matlab PC is not a matrix, but a vector. Is this by design?

Comment: I got MATLAB PC from PCA(*some data*). I thought PCA returns rotation matrix. If I calculate eigenvector from eig() will it work.

Comment: I got some clue why the differences are coming. The conversion of rotm2quat(PC) is highly machine precision. How many floating points are in PC variable the answer is depends on them.  But the good thing is that quat2rotm(A) does not have machine machine precision.

Comment: @Stefan: that is a 3x3 matrix in MATLAB syntax, not a vector. You're confused maybe with Python syntax?

Answer (score 1):

PC is not a valid direction cosine (i.e., rotation) matrix.  The determinant should be close to 1, but it is actually close to -1.  Feeding this PC to any routine expecting a direction cosine matrix will not produce correct results.  You need to examine how you are generating this PC matrix and fix it.  I can't even reproduce your quaternion.  E.g.,

```matlab
>> PC=[0.4822    0.5070    0.7145
   -0.4086    0.8516   -0.3285
    0.7750    0.1336   -0.6177]; 
>> det(PC)
ans =
   -1.0001   <-- bad
>> quat=rotm2quat(PC)
quat =
    0.9427    0.2430   -0.1641   -0.1590
```